# Integrated Windows Authentication using NTLMv2

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-authentication, ntlm

I'm trying to achieve NTLMv2 type authentication but I'm having problems making it work.

I have configured the client to send the `Type-1` GET request using the server's `hostname` and the `domain` I'm in.
The server responds with a `401 Unauthorized` challenge along with a `WWW-Authorize: NTLM <base64-msg>`. The base64 contains the following:

```
byte[] msg = {(byte) 'N', (byte) 'T', (byte) 'L', (byte) 'M', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'P', (byte) '\0',
        0x02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, /*msg*/0x28, 0/*length*/, 0, 0, 0x01, (byte) 0b10000010, 0, 0,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, //nonce
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

After that point, I was expecting Internet Explorer to automatically send the `Type-3` response that will contain the username and the encrypted challenge using the password hash but instead it does nothing.

I have setup my local IP under the `Local Intranet` settings and have changed the custom level to use `Automatic logon with current username and password`.

Should I be doing something manually after receiving the challenge response from the server? I need the browser to do the encryption since I don't have access to the current user's credentials.

The server side component is a custom `Java application` running on `Tomcat 8.0.45`. Although I believe it shouldn't be related, I'm adding this in case it is. Also note that the server might also be behind a proxy sometimes (usually in the form of an `Apache HTTPD`).

Comment: What web application platform are you using?  Apache?  Tomcat?  JBOSS?  Please also add the tag to the question.

Comment: @JohnRSmith Added the extra info. I thought it should be unrelated but just in case.

Comment: Where did you get the NTLMv2 module for Tomcat?  Post a link and I'll try to repro.

Comment: @T-Heron There is no module. Tomcat responds the byte array you see in the question. It's just a servlet call

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to know how it works under the hood, if you are using IE, but there are details below.

If IE is not responding, you may have a zone conflict. If the IP applies to more than one zone, things get confusing. I'd verify you add the site to trusted sites and make sure the Automatic setting is set for that zone.

I have had great luck with Eric Glass's code and explanations.  http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html 
The Java in the apendix works and I have had great luck converting it to c# with almost no need to change anything.

Comment: I'm still confused. I have implemented the logic for Type-1 and Type-2 messages but I was expected IE to do the Type-3 messages automatically. Is that how it is supposed to work?